# why is AltCHunks empty at "insert" point?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have a sharepoint Doc Set.
In it is a template, and 1 to n doc that need to be merged.

I'm using code from [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff519529(v=office.14).aspx)

Everything is working swimmingly until the altChunks "assignment of data" (although it writes a corrupt file that has to be "Open and REpair" opened, but I'm tackling that in another question.

The template document is opened in memory rather than "directly" or "in place" because its a sharepoint file (i guess??) using Open XML.  The memory stream is getting the "Open Binary" write, but I can't seem to find a location in the altChunk to verify the FeedData is working.... In the InsertAfter, the altchunk inner text is ""  (empty)

THe following code is being called once for each file to be added:
      void AddAltChunk(MainDocumentPart mainPart, Word.SdtElement sdt, SPFile filename,bool LastPass)
        {
            string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + id;
            id++;
            byte[] byteArray = filename.OpenBinary();

```
        AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
        AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);

        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            mem.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length); //mem.length grows after this
            mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            chunk.FeedData(mem);  //dunno if this workin
        }

        Word.AltChunk altChunk = new Word.AltChunk();
        altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
        //Replace content control with altChunk information 

        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement parent = sdt.Parent;
        parent.InsertAfter(altChunk, sdt);  //altChunk "inner text" is empty (just guessing that it should have the info to be written)
        if (LastPass) { sdt.Remove(); }
     }
```

So then here is the "write" part.....it writes out a file that has the original template, but no text from the files that were supposedly merged.

Other extraneous info:
The code says use "template dotx" to start, then writes "doc docx"...THAT makes a file that can't be opened or repaired.
I modified the template to be a DOCX and I get a corrupt file that CAN open using Open and Repair.
THe documents are of a "content type" that I made & applied to teh library so when they click "new" they get a blank of THAT doc (with some content controls)....this is makes the 1 to many docs to be merged.....I wonder if Content COntrols are trouble?...although I put a 'regular" doc in there that has no CC's and one line of "general text" & not even that is "merged".

FLumuxed.    And I'm (obviously to you pros) a newb at C#, so talk to me like I'm 7 yrs old :)

Comment: Guess I wore out my welcome w/ all of you?